# PHP - Access MSSQL datetime column from the returned array

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays

PHP - Access MSSQL datetime column from the returned array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CallId] => 45
            [CallLoginId] => 1
            [CustomerId] => 140
            [CallOptionId] => 2
            [CallTypeId] => 2
            [CallStatusId] => 1
            [CallDateTime] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2012-06-28 00:00:00
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
                )

            [ContactNo] => 45151551115
            [ContactPerson] => Contact Person name
            [ProductId] => 1
            [ProdCompanyId] => 1
            [ProdCategoryId] => 1
            [ModelNo] => 451212151
            [ProdUnderId] => 1
            [Problem] => Simple Problem Details 
            [Remarks] => Remarks 
            [Accessories] => Accessories 
            [CallCaseId] => 
            [CallCaseDate] => 
            [ServiceCharge] => 0
            [CourierName] => 
            [DocketNo] => 
            [CompanyId] => 126
            [ASPId] => 130
            [InsBy] => 134
            [InsDate] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2012-06-23 17:04:51
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
                )

            [UpdBy] => 11
            [UpdDate] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2012-06-28 18:29:23
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
                )

            [FName] => Kumar
            [MName] => a
            [LName] => Customer
            [ProductName] => LenovoDesktop420
            [CallOption] => InHouse
            [CallType] => H.W.Installation
            [ProdCompany] => Lenovo
            [ProdCategory] => Desktop
            [ProdUnder] => AMC
            [CallStatus] => Open
            [EntityId] => 134
            [InsertBy] => Bhavin   Rana
        )

)
```

how can access date time value form this returned array ? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an outer array with numerically indexed one element `[0]`, which is an associative array. `CallDateTime` as a key of that array is a `DateTime` object.

```
$array[0]['CallDateTime']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')  // 2012-06-28 00:00:00
$array[0]['CallDateTime']->getTimezone()->getName()    // Asia/Kolkata

// Same with InsDate and UpdDate
$array[0]['InsDate']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')         // 2012-06-23 17:04:51
$array[0]['InsDate']->getTimezone()->getName()           // Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DateTime as array in C:\inetpub... where echo $this->CallDetail [0]['ContactNo']; works fine.

Comment: @BhavinRana Oops sorry I misread the data structure. Those are objects and therefore you need to access their properties via `->`

Comment: tried with  echo $this->CallDetail[0]['CallDateTime']->date ; Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date in C:\inetpub\...

Comment: `var_dump($this->CallDetail[0]['CallDateTime'])`.  The property is clearly there from your structure above.

Comment: above var_dump = object(DateTime)#85 (3) {   ["date"]=>   string(19) "2012-06-28 00:00:00"   ["timezone_type"]=>   int(3)   ["timezone"]=>   string(12) "Asia/Kolkata" }

Comment: @BhavinRana Interesting! I was seeing the date property. Due to [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382) you cannot get the date property unless you call `var_dump()` on it first as I had in my testing.  Instead, use `format()` and `getTimezone()->getName()` as I have changed above.

Comment: your rock ! Great Work Many Thanks !